# Minimum Weight Binary Spanning Tree

Tags: trees, minimum-spanning-tree

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a simple graph with weights $w_{ij}$ (can be assumed to be positive). Is it possible to find the minimum (or maximum) weight, rooted spanning tree that is binary? That means every node has a degree at most 3, which would correspond to a parent and two children?

Comment: Would you accept a counterexample as an answer?